# React Hooks Remove item from array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my react hooks component I am rendering data from an array of objects.

```
const lineInfo = [
  {
    id: '001',
    line: 's-1125026',
    arrival: '7:30',
    departure: '8:00',
    authorization: 'User 1',

  },
  {
    id: '002',
    line: 's-1125027',
    arrival: '8:01',
    departure: '8:50',
    authorization: 'User 1',
  },
```

In the `.map()` I'm returning data using this data:

```
       <div>
         {lineInfo.map((line) => (
              <Row key={`line_${line.id}`}>

 // remaining code removed for length
```

The list returns fine, so now I am trying to remove a row from the list.
**Remove func**

```
  const [list, setList] = useState(lineInfo);

  function handleRemove(id) {
    console.log('id' id);
    const newList = list.filter((line) => line.id !== id);
    setList(newList);
  }
```

**Remove Button**

```
        <Button
          className={style.close_button}
          onClick={() => handleRemove(line.id)}
         >
           <img src={close} alt="trash" />
        </Button>
</Row>
```

The problem I am running into is that in my console log, is that only the line.id is being removed from the array instead of the whole row of data.

1. How do I remove all the data belonging to a particular id?
2. Even though the console log shows that the text is removed, why is the text that is displayed in my row not removed from the view?

I'm not too familiar with hooks and have only been able to find examples of my particular problem with class components. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe a codesandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should display the defined state with the hook. in this case the `list` , and not the `lineInfo`.

```
 <div>
   {list.map((line) => (
     <Row key={`line_${line.id}`}>

 // remaining code removed for length
```

Comment: Thank you. I totally didn't realize that because I used ```lineInfo``` in my the ```useState```  constant that I would need to change it in the map also.

Comment: You need to change it, because in react scope, the non `*useHook*` variables, are not reactive

Answer (score 1):

You should not render lineInfo, render the list from local state instead:

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;
const lineInfo = [
  {
    id: '001',
    line: 's-1125026',
    arrival: '7:30',
    departure: '8:00',
    authorization: 'User 1',
  },
  {
    id: '002',
    line: 's-1125027',
    arrival: '8:01',
    departure: '8:50',
    authorization: 'User 1',
  },
];
//make row pure component using React.memo
const Row = React.memo(function Row({ item, remove }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(item, undefined, 2)}</pre>
      <button onClick={() => remove(item.id)}>
        remove
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(lineInfo);
  //make remove a callback that is only created
  //  on App mount using useCallback with no dependencies
  const remove = useCallback(
    (removeId) =>
      //pass callback to setList so list is not a dependency
      //  of this callback
      setList((list) =>
        list.filter(({ id }) => id !== removeId)
      ),
    []
  );

  return (
    <ul>
      {list.map((line) => (
        <Row
          key={`line_${line.id}`}
          item={line}
          remove={remove}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```